# Negative response 00000436 found

Tags: java, sms, smpp, jsmpp

I got this error when I'm trying to send sms via SMPP connection.

```
org.jsmpp.extra.NegativeResponseException: Negative response 00000436 found
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.validateResponse(AbstractSession.java:215)
    at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.executeSendCommand(AbstractSession.java:271)
    at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.submitShortMessage(SMPPSession.java:320)
```

I'm using jsmpp-2.1.0.jar

Here is SMS push code

```
messageId = GlobalConstants.SMPP_SESSION_BULK.submitShortMessage("CMT", TypeOfNumber.INTERNATIONAL.ALPHANUMERIC, NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN, mtport, TypeOfNumber.INTERNATIONAL, NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN, sentNumber, new ESMClass(), (byte)0, (byte)1,  null, null, new RegisteredDelivery(SMSCDeliveryReceipt.SUCCESS_FAILURE), (byte)0, new GeneralDataCoding(), (byte)0, message.getBytes());
```

Does "SMSC returned error code 0x00000436" and "Negative response 00000436 found" are same errors? I couldn't find error code : 00000436 on smpp error list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the **Short Message Peer to PeerProtocol Specification v3.4** 
errors 0x00000400-0x000004FF Are Reserved for SMSC vendor specific
errors. So you might need to check with your SMSC to get the exact problem.

In our case we got the  Negative response 00000436 because we were sending the destination address with + 5520000000804 which needs to be sent without the +

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the credentials/username/password/system id are correct.